# Living in Switzerland but having employment with a German company

Tags: germany, blue-card, switzerland

I am a non-EU national and working+living in Germany with a Blue Card permit. I am getting married to a EU national who is working in Switzerland and we are planning to move together. After marriage I should also get a work permit for Switzerland, but I am not sure I will find a job that fits my experience. Do you know whether it is possible to become a Swiss resident but continue to work with my current German employer? I would love to be able to pay taxes in Switzerland by becoming a Swiss tax resident as well.

Comment: Are you thinking of cross-border commuting or working remotely from Switzerland? Can your current employer somehow offer some sort of Swiss contract? Commuting might be difficult, you will need to maintain a German work permit like the EU Blue Card but those can explicitly be invalidated if you live outside Germany. At least, thanks to your EU spouse, you don't have to worry about the permission to work and reside in Switzerland so if your employer can find a way to employ you in Switzerland, they don't need to worry about visa sponsorship.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EU Blue Card - Working for a German company while living outside of EU](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12761/eu-blue-card-working-for-a-german-company-while-living-outside-of-eu)